# Automatic Parsing of Custom struct when Nullable

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have a custom struct that looks like the below:

```
public struct Date
{
    private int _year;
    private int _month;
    private int _day;
    public Date(string myDate)
    {
        var date = DateTime.ParseExact(myDate, "yyyy-MM-dd");
        _year = date.Year;
        _month = date.Month;
        _day = date.Day;
    }
    public int Year => _year;
    public int Month => _month;
    public int Day => _day;
}
```

This is on a model that can get posted to my webApi, that looks like this:

```
public class MyData
{
    public int? MyIntValue {get;set;}
    public string MyStringValue {get;set;}
    public Date? MyDateValue {get;set;}
}
```

where non-nullable types are made nullable as they are optional for this message.

Given a message that looks like the below, posted to my webApi

```
{
    "MyIntValue": 5,
    "MyStringValue": "Hello",
    "MyDateValue": "2019-03-29"
}
```

I want to be able to take that string, and parse it into my `Date` struct.

My first port of call is a `TypeConverter` decorating my `Date` struct
So I've written a converter `DateConverter` that looks like the below.

```
public class DateConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConverterFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return sourceType == typeof(string) || base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value is string stringValue)
        {
            return new Date(stringValue);
        }
        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
}
```

And decorated my `Date` struct with `[TypeConverter(typeof(DateConverter))]`

This however doesn't work. After some (lengthy) investigation I believe it's because the type on the model is actually a `Nullable<T>`. So after some more digging I've found a `NullableConverter`. Modifications to my `TypeConverter` make it now look like this

```
public class DateConverter : NullableConverter
{
    public DateConverter() : base(typeof(Date?)) {}

    public override bool CanConverterFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return sourceType == typeof(string) || base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value is string stringValue)
        {
            return new Date(stringValue);
        }
        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
}
```

I am now seeing the `DateConverter` constructor get hit (yay!) when posting in the message, however I get stuck in a loop that results in a `StackOverflowException` because I believe when `NullableConverter` is given a Nullable Type in its constructor, it looks at the underlying type and resolves its TypeConverter, if any, and continues in that fashion. As I've set the `NullableConverter` on the `Date` struct it is constantly resolving to `DateConverter` and going around and around...

This is where my investigation has stopped. I can find precious little information on `NullableConverter` now or any real usages of it as a `TypeConverter` decorating a type and I'm certain this is the class I need to be using.

Have I done anything wrong? Am I close but just not quite over the hump... or am I looking at the entirely wrong aspect of this.

My question is this:

How can I get the given Json into my WebAPI where the `MyDateValue` is correctly parsed into my custom type

N.B. The Model is generated code and as such I would prefer not to decorate the member on my model (If that would even work, I havn't tried). However if that is the ONLY way this can work I will pose this change to interested parties my side and see what uptake there is.

Further investigation shows that if I revert to my previous `TypeConverter` (Not `NullableConverter`) then `CanConvertFrom` is called, and returns true, but `ConvertFrom` is then not subsequently called. It also then appears to not call `CanConvertFrom` again. Maybe Asp.Net internally caches the result for that type.